# Opposite of "reach a settlement" in a lawsuit?

Tags: phrase-requests, antonyms

Is there a common phrase for the opposite of reaching a settlement in a lawsuit? That is, is there a common phrase for going to court and having a judge reach a decision?

Comment: The case has gone to trial.  Or afterwards: The case was decided in court.

Comment: Came to an *impasse*.

Comment: "Fail to settle", "fail to reach a settlement" which will lead to a trial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite of reaching a settlement in a civil legal dispute is the idiomatic usage to *to go* or *to take* to trial.  From *[The 10 Stupidest Mistakes Men Make When Facing Divorce: And How to Avoid Them](https://books.google.com/books?id=5VkwjWrJipQC&pg=PA48&dq=%22take%20to%20trial%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBGoVChMI-vay3NSWyQIVAT4mCh3_HAVU#v=onepage&q=%22take%20to%20trial%22&f=false)* by J Cordell:

Even if you would rather settle than **go to trial** and most men would, because going to trial is a lot of preparation and pressure for them, too—then the best way to force a settlement is to show that your case is strong enough to **take to trial**.

In criminal matters in the US, settling the case without trial between the state and the accused is called reaching a plea agreement, and the language for the failure to agree on a plea is the same. From *[Handbook Of Eyewitness Psychology](https://books.google.com/books?id=UoKOAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA235&dq=%22go%20to%20trial%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAWoVChMInfHslNaWyQIVjOkmCh0G9Q0m#v=onepage&q=%22go%20to%20trial%22&f=false)* by R C Lindsay, D F Ross, J D Read, and M P Toglia:

> This pretrial pleading has the effect of changing the proportions of
>   innocent and guilty persons who choose to **go to trial**, an effect
>   we call the pleading effect.

And from *[The Language of Bribery Cases](https://books.google.com/books?id=XdTiAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&dq=%22take%20to%20trial%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwADgKahUKEwijwcuF1pbJAhVIQCYKHSIoDXw#v=onepage&q=%22take%20to%20trial%22&f=false)* by R W Shuy:

> The FBI investigation produced language evidence that even the
>   prosecutor, to his credit, finally found inadequate to **take to
>   trial**, proving that good intelligence analysis can overcome faulty
>   intelligence gathering,....

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about going to court **and** having a judge (a jury, or in some cases an arbitrator) reach a decision, the word is 'adjudicate'. So the word to use in antonymical phrasing of 'reaching a settlement' is 'adjudicated':

> We couldn't reach a settlement, so the case had to be adjudicated.
>
> **adjudicate** v.tr.
>   1. To make a decision (in a legal case or proceeding), as where a judge or arbitrator rules on some disputed issue or claim between the parties.

[adjudicate. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved November 17 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adjudicate.]

Comment: The problem is "a plaintiff or defendant" reaches a settlement. But they don't "adjudicate". A judge or arbitrator adjudicates.

Comment: @Rathony, the *case* or *issue* is settled or adjudicated. There are no plaintiff or defendants until the case is *at trial*, but many *cases* are settled out of court. So I'm not seeing any problem, or at least not the one you are.

Comment: @Rathony, I should probably add that the OP specifically asked for a phrase meaning "having a **judge** reach a decision".

Comment: Settlements can be reached during trial. They are not settled by judges or arbitrators. They are settled by plaintiffs and defendants. Also, the case or issue is adjudicated by a judge or (possibly an arbitrator). There is difference.

Comment: @Rathony, so what is the problem with what?

Comment: [Adjudicate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adjudicate) is synonymous with "rule/judge" in a verbal sense. It is not having a judge reach a decision. It is "for a judge" to reach a decision.

Comment: @Rathony, no matter how you slice it, having a case or issue adjudicated is indeed having a judge (etc.) reach a decision in court.